# Laravel eloquent where method gives without case sensitve

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my laravel project I am using repository pattern. I created following method to get brand by it's name from the brand table.

```
public function getBrandByName($name){
   return $this->model->where('name','=',$name)->first();
}
```

In brand table I have record with name = "BrandOne". But when I call method with case sensitivity as **getBrandByName('brandone')** or **getBrandByName('BrandOne')** it both gives me the row.But I only need to get the record with case sensitivity. How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: This is usually to do with the collation on your database. What database are you using?

Comment: @Jonathon: i use mysql database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Case sensitivity is something that is controlled at database level. The *collation* that you use on your tables determines how characters are treated and ordered. A case-insensitive collation treats both upper and lowercase characters as the same.

Assuming you're using MySQL, if you have a collation that ends in `_ci` then it means you're using a case-insensitive collation.

You're able to set the collation you want to use in your Laravel database settings:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

You can change `collation` here to a case-sensitive collation and once your tables have been created with this new collation, MySQL will treat upper and lowercase characters differently.

Collations that end with `_cs` or `_bin` are usually case-sensitive.

Please note though, that this change will not take effect until you re-migrate your database (or change collation manually) as the collation is set when your tables are created.

---

It is possible to do a case-sensitive comparison using MySQL though, but I don't think it's supported out of the box by Laravel, so you'll have to use a raw query for it.

Comment: Yes my database is mysql and collation ends with _ci. Thanks alot

Comment: Yes I used the raw query and it worked like a charm.  thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

use `DB::raw()` method and then:

```
public function getBrandByName($name){
   return $this->model->where(DB::raw("BINARY `name`"), $name)->first();
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Yes I used the raw query and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot